# Dynamic table with data attributes

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, html-table, haml, custom-data-attribute

I have a dynamically created table with the row and column numbers stored as data attributes in each cell:

```
%table
  - (1..3).each do |row|
    %tr
      - (1..3).each do |column|
        %td.cell{:data => {:x => column, :y => row}}
```

The HTML this generates is fine, except that whenever the column equals the row, `data-y` is missing:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-x='1'></td>
    <td data-x='2' data-y='1'></td>
    <td data-x='3' data-y='1'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-x='1' data-y='2'></td>
    <td data-x='2'></td>
    <td data-x='3' data-y='2'></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td data-x='1' data-y='3'></td>
    <td data-x='2' data-y='3'></td>
    <td data-x='3'></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Anyone know what's causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug in Haml version 4.0.0](https://github.com/haml/haml/pull/641). It’s fixed in [4.0.1.rc.1](https://rubygems.org/gems/haml/versions/4.0.1.rc.1) – the fix hasn’t made it into a full release as of writing this but you should be okay with the rc1 gem.